# ../Core/Src/main.c(25): error: #5: cannot open source input file "DC_MOTOR.h": No such file or directory

Tags: c

```
BUTTONS.c(57): error:  #513: a value of type "uint8_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "float *"
```

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t Filter_Order;
    uint16_t Buffer_Index;
    FILTER_DATA_TYPE* Data_Buffer;
    float* Filter_Coeffecients;
}FIR_Filter_cfg;

 FIR_Filter_cfg BTNS_Filters[BTN_UNITS] = {0};
 uint8_t Filters_Buffers[BTN_UNITS][BTNS_FILTER_ORDER+1] = {0};
 BTNS_Filters[i].Data_Buffer = Filters_Buffers[i];
```

The struct is in header file.
Any suggestions what the reason is?

Comment: The problem is with the last line from the code

Comment: What has the title to do with the actual error? Please decide, and [edit] your question accordingly. And then, please elaborate what in detail you don't understand of the error message.